# Integer expected error in shell

Tags: awk, sed, sh

I have the following script i am building to send an alert about java heap space.

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep [t]omcat | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PID

/usr/java/bin/jstat -gcutil $PID | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3, $4}' | while read output; do
espace=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/.\{3\}$//' )
ospace=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/.\{3\}$//' )

echo $espace
echo $ospace
if [ "$opsace" -ge "85" ]; then
  echo "Old Gen Heap getting full on $(hostname) on $(date)" >> /tmp/$$
fi
done

if [ -s /tmp/$$ ]
then
sendEmail -f blah@blah.com \
          -t $EMAILTO \
          -u "Disk Space Alert at $(hostname)" \
          -s $SMTP \
          -xu $SMTP_USER \
          -xp $SMTP_PASS \
          -l /tmp/$$.log \
          -o tls=yes -q \
           < /tmp/$$ &
fi
```

Here is the output when i run this command.

```
[root in /i/admin]# sh checkheapspace.sh 
4306
80
77
checkheapspace.sh: line 20: [: : integer expression expected
```

I am not sure why it thinks 77 is not an integer.  It stock form it is a decimal, so i use sed to take the last 3 characters off the variables.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Use `set -x` when running your script, or `bash -x yourscript`, and give the exact output this gives for the line at issue. (This will show any hidden characters which `echo` obscures).

Comment: Actually -- it's a typo. `opsace` isn't `ospace`.

Comment: (BTW, this is an error on a line that doesn't call awk at all; why is it tagged that way? And on a side note, piping from awk to sed is silly; `awk` can do everything `sed` can and more).

Comment: ...and on yet another side note, `echo $output` is buggy; you want `echo "$output"` instead unless you want globs to be expanded, tabs and newlines changed to spaces, dogs and cats living together, etc.

Comment: Even that isn't perfect -- if `output=-n`, for instance, then even `echo "$output"` will do nothing. `printf '%s\n' "$output"` is a more genuinely robust alternative.

Comment: ...a bunch of your other expansions need quotes too. See http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ "$opsace" -ge "85" ]; then
#       ^^
```

...is not...

```
if [ "$ospace" -ge "85" ]; then
#       ^^
```

---

Thus, this is running:

```
if [ '' -ge 85 ]
```

...and an empty string is indeed not an integer.